# Can't send a multipart/form-data from a react view with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, multipartform-data

How to send a multipart/form-data from a javascript view to a rails controller?

I'm trying to make a form able to send a file (image)  to my backend controller, so I am adding this on the headers of my Axios call:

```
 axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
```

I add it within my functional component, anyways checking the network i see :

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

and the parameters received in the controller are empty (for the file)

---

I have:

```
  const handlePhoto = (e) => {
    const image = new FormData();
    image.append('photo', e.target.files[0]);
    console.log("inside habdlephoto", image.get('photo'))
    const dataSend = Object.assign({} ,data, image.get('photo'));
    setData(dataSend)
  }
```

which I use in

```
                      <Input
                        type="file"
                        innerRef={register}
                        name="photo"
                        onChange={handlePhoto}
                        multiple={true}
                      />
```

the axios call looks like:

```
    const config = {
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
   }

    axios
    .post("../../../api/v1/products/create.json", { product: {...data, ...dataRegister} }, config )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not setting the headers correctly for the request.

Try to set the `headers` via the [request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```js
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',file)
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
    axios.post(url, formData, config)
```

Comment: still not working, but the headers do update this time,  I will update with what I have now